# C# WPF MVVM - Command not Working?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, command

I'm currently creating my first MVVM application after months of experimenting with WinForms-like WPF coding.

This program is the MVVM version of an application I've already made, an MP3 player called Tornado Player.

At the moment I'm working on the first element, 'Watch Folders' - folders which use the `FileSystemWatcher` to automatically add MP3 files to your playlist if you add new files to that folder.

These folders are all view-able in a `ListBox`, the source of which is bound to a property of type `ObservableCollection<WatchFolder>`.

Each element in the `ListBox` has a `ContextMenu` with two `MenuItem`s: 'Open' and 'Remove'. `Open` will open the folder in a new instance of `explorer.exe`. This is what I'm trying to get to work, for the moment. I'll deal with `Remove` later.

This is my View for the ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding WatchFolders}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedWatchFolder}" Margin="5">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="/Tornado Player;component/Images/Folder.png" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path}" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <ListBox.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ContextMenu>
                                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding OpenWatchFolder}" Header="Open" FontWeight="Bold">
                                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                                            <Image Source="/Tornado Player;component/Images/Folder Open.png"/>
                                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                                    </MenuItem>

                                    <Separator/>

                                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding DeleteWatchFolder}" Header="Remove">
                                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                                            <Image Source="/Tornado Player;component/Images/Delete.png"/>
                                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.Resources>
            </ListBox>
```

My ViewModel is as follows (in the constructor, I've added a `WatchFolder` at `C:\Documents` for testing purposes):

```
class ViewModelMain : ViewModelBase
{
    public ViewModelMain()
    {
        WatchFolders = new ObservableCollection<WatchFolder>();

        OpenWatchFolder = new RelayCommand(DoOpenWatchFolder);

        WatchFolders.Add(new WatchFolder() { Path = "C:\\Documents" });
    }

    //Contains all of the Watch Folders as shown in the Watch Folders tab
    public ObservableCollection<WatchFolder> WatchFolders { get; set; }

    WatchFolder selectedWatchFolder;
    public WatchFolder SelectedWatchFolder
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedWatchFolder;
        }
        set
        {
            if (selectedWatchFolder != value)
            {
                selectedWatchFolder = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedWatchFolder");
            }
        }
    }

    //'Watch Folders' tab commands
    public RelayCommand OpenWatchFolder { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand DeleteWatchFolder { get; set; }

    void DoOpenWatchFolder(object parameter)
    {
        Process.Start(SelectedWatchFolder.Path);
    }
}
```

My model of the `WatchFolder` is as follows:

```
class WatchFolder : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string path;
    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return path;
        }
        set
        {
            if (path != value)
            {
                path = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Path");
            }
        }
    }

    internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

My `RelayCommand` code is as follows:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

I've tried troubleshooting this for a while, but I do not understand this design pattern and some of the keywords well enough to see what is wrong. I've tried various different solutions and debugging, but none of them worked, and the debugger won't even reach the code for the execution of the command.

Clicking the `MenuItem` `Open` will not execute the block of code that does `Process.Start(path)`. I don't know why this doesn't work, so I was wondering if anyone knows?

Comment: You framed up the question but never provided the actual question or elaborated on what the actual issue is? What code is not being executed? Is anything being executed? Have you narrowed it down by chance?

Comment: Edited to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` of the `ContextMenu` is the `WatchFolder` object and not the `ViewModelMain` object. The `DataContext` of each `ListBoxItem` container in a `ListBox` is the data object in the `ItemsSource` that represents the current row in the `ListBox`.

You could bind the `Tag` property of the `ListBoxItem` to the `DataContext` of the parent `ListBox` (which is the `ViewModelMain` object) using a `RelativeSource` binding and then bind the `Command` property of the `MenuItem` to the `OpenWatchFolder` property of the `Tag` property of the `ContextMenu`.

This works:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" />
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.OpenWatchFolder,
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" Header="Open" FontWeight="Bold">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="/Tornado Player;component/Images/Folder Open.png"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>

                <Separator/>

                <MenuItem Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DeleteWatchFolder, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" Header="Remove">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="/Tornado Player;component/Images/Delete.png"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```